# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

SOLVED: short_open_tag was off, that's the problem. Turning it on and everything work now!

I'm currently making a theme and this happens. I don't understand why the code did not work. I've read some similar topic about this but they don't help resolving my problem:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\boxtruyen\single-ngan.php** on line **105**

Please help, I could not figure out the error!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()):?>
    <?php while (have_posts()):?>
    <?php the_post(); tw_views($ID_parent); ?>
    <input id="id_post" type="hidden" value="<?=$ID_parent?>">
    <div class="container" id="truyen">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-truyen-main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-info-desc" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
                    <div class="title-list">
                        <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?the_title()?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <style>
                            .fix_color {
                                color: #C1377F;
                            }
                            .fix_color a {
                                color: #C1377F;
                            }
                        </style>
                        Đăng bởi <span class="fix_color"><?the_author()?></span>, lúc <span class="fix_color"><?the_time()?></span>, tại <span class="fix_color"><?the_category(', ')?></span>
                        <br/> Đọc:
                        <?php tw_views(get_the_ID());?>
                        <?php echo tw_get_views(get_the_ID())?>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <img class="image_ngan" src="<?=tw_get_thumbnail()?>" alt="<?the_title()?>" itemprop="image" />
                        <?php the_content()?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
                    <div class="ads-780-90">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'qc-780x90');?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-lg">
                    <div class="ads-320-100">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'qc-320x100');?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row visible-md visible-lg">
                <div class="col-xs-12 comment-box">
                    <div class="title-list">
                        <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Bình luận</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?the_permalink()?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 comment-box">
                    <div class="title-list">
                        <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Cùng Chuyên Mục</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cungchuyenmuc">
                        <style>
                            .cungchuyenmuc li {
                                list-style: none;
                                width: 20%;
                                padding: 15px;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <?php $args=array( 'post_type'=> array('ngan'), 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $related_number, 'post__not_in' => array($ID_parent), 'orderby' => 'RAND' ); $list = new wp_query($args); ?>
                        <?php while($list->have_posts()):?>
                        <?php $list->the_post()?>
                        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="<?the_permalink()?>">
                                <img style="max-width:100%;width:100%;max-height: 160px" src="<?=tw_get_thumbnail()?>" alt="<?the_title()?>"/><br/>
                                <h3 style="margin:8px 0px;text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #bbb"><?the_title()?></h3>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?endwhile;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 text-center col-truyen-side">
            <div class="ads-300-250"></div>
            <div class="list list-truyen col-xs-12">
                <div class="title-list">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Truyện đang hot</h4>
                </div>
                <?php $args=array( 'post_type'=> 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $so_truyen_dang_hot, 'post__not_in' => array($ID_parent), 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'tw_views_post', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' ); $list = new wp_query($args); ?>
                <?while($list->have_posts()):?>
                    <?$list->the_post();?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                <a href="<?the_permalink()?>" title="<?the_title()?>">
                                    <?the_title()?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?endwhile;?>
            </div>
            <div class="ads-300-600">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'qc-300x600'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: did you got short tag enabled? try `<?php` for all instance.

Comment: You are right, the problem is short tag was not enable! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use php short tags like `<?endwhile;?>` instead use `<?php endwhile; ?>`. Replace all short tags with `<?php ?>`.